# How to store a Star-Model database in Elastic search

Tags: json, database, elasticsearch, mapping

i'm a total NooB at elastic-Search and i researched on the internet how to store highly related table with elastic search but it's quite confusing, here's my problem,

I have Approximately 16 Tables (one fact table and the other are dimensions tables), i could do a SQL request where i join all the table in an array of long rows containing all the fields and mapping it in a Json way, but there will be tons of duplicated fields,

For example the dimension table A " contain 3 persons: p1,p2,p3" and a Fact Table contain more than 1000 row (for examples) and all these row have foreign keys/references to these 3 persons,

So what's the ideal way to store it?

putting each table in a different Index or category or to embed everything in one single object per row ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `facts` can form an index with their `dimension` field denormalised. And create a separate index for `dimensions`.

```
PUT /dimension_1/1
{
  "name": "John Smith" 
}
PUT /dimension_2/1
{
  "name": "John Doe" 
}
...



PUT /facts/1
{
  "title":    "facts",
  "name":     "p1",
  "dimension_1":     {
    "id":       1,
    "name":     "John Smith" 
  },
  "dimension_2":     {
    "id":       1,
    "name":     "John Doe" 
  }
...
}
```

Refer 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization.html

Comment: Thank's for the answer,

So the fact sub-tree from of the index, will contain all the fields that are joined with it the fact table, so having duplicate doesn't bother that much ? considering that there won't be any Update to the existing rows.

Comment: But if you do this, and the name on one of the dimension changes (say, John Doe gets updated to Jane Doe, but same Id), you would still need to perform the update not only on the dimension, but also on all of the records on the `facts` index that have this denormalized value, or am I missing something? I'm also trying to find a better way to do this but so far haven't been able to find a good solution.